# Using the zip method in Python to count character equality in 2 strings according to their index

Tags: python

Im trying to write a piece of code that compares the charcters of two strings and then shows how many characters match.

This is how i've started out however I dont know how to actually use this method to compare two strings.

```
password = 'BADGED'

guess = 'BALDER'
    
for p, g in zip(password, guess):
```

Any help and advice is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Im trying to match the characters in their respective order.

Comment: Well, you've successfully written a loop over pairs of characters. Do you know how to do an equality comparison? Do you know how to increment a counter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use zip, then you will only check the serial pairs.
You need two loops to check for matches that can go in different order.

```
password = 'BADGED'

guess = 'BALDER'

answer = 0
for p in password:
    for g in guess:
        if p == g:
            answer += 1
            
print(answer)
```

If you want exactly consecutive pairs, just use the postcode or postcode link.

## Variant with indexes

Please note that if the strings are of different lengths, an error will be thrown.

```
password = 'BADGED'

guess = 'BALDER'

answer = 0
for i in range(len(password)):
    if password[i] == guess[i]:
        answer += 1

print(answer)
```

## Variant with iterators

```
password = 'BADGED'

guess = 'BALDER'

answer = 0
for p, g in zip(password, guess):
    if p == g:
        answer += 1

print(answer)
```

Comment: Sorry i should have specified. I am actually looking for matched characters in their respective order.

Comment: I completed my answer, @Drosii

Answer (score 2):

I'd wrap it in a function like this:

```
def matches(s1, s2):
    matches = []
    for c1, c2 in zip(s1, s2):
        if c1 == c2:
            matches.append(c1)
    return matches
```

Output:

```
>>> matches('TEST', 'TEST')
['T', 'E', 'S', 'T']
>>> matches('BADGED', 'BALDER')
['B', 'A', 'E']
```

Answer (score 0):

This gonna work for the strings with the same length:

```
password = 'BADGED'
guess = 'BALDER'
answer = 0
for p, g in zip(password, guess):
    if p==g :
        answer +=1

print(answer)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will compute the ratio of similarity between the two string in there respective order. Before, please install fuzzywuzzy using this command: pip install fuzzywuzzy

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

password = 'BADGED'

guess = 'BALDER'

print(fuzz.ratio(password,guess))
```